# Proof of Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand the step highlighted in green.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might help you:

As $q_i$s are linear combinations of $a_i$s, then any linear combination of $q_i$s is again a linear combination of $a_i$s.

Comment: So as {a_1,a_2} linearly independent, span R^2 the result follows?

Comment: yes! more or less you are correct!